# Google Glass Sqlite Access

Tags: google-glass

Is it possible to read/write to a database from a Google Glass GDK app?  To clarify, I'm referring to the GDK, not the Mirror API.  On standard Android, you use android.database.sqlite.  Is this package available in Glass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since the Glass platform is based on Android, you can use the same APIs for local file storage and database access that you would use on other Android devices.